# Signal protocol: are One-time prekeys derived from Signed Prekey or just randomly generated?

Tags: signature, protocol-design, signal-protocol

Do [signal protocol](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/) derive One-time prekeys from Signed Prekey with some KDF or are they just randomly generated in the same way as Signed Prekey?

Comment: [What is not clear in 3.3?](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/x3dh.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the protocol leaves it up to the implementor to choose how to sample the prekeys. That said, there is no reason to do anything but sample them randomly. Indeed that's what the [Android](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/blob/23c7e5dc3fc1df7914afd0672f318fa7b2d7fc27/app/src/main/java/org/thoughtcrime/securesms/crypto/PreKeyUtil.java#L67-L72) and [iOS](https://github.com/signalapp/SignalServiceKit/blob/5c3b30104a7a642d7ff70250e0b81ca645938dec/src/Storage/AxolotlStore/TSStorageManager%2BPreKeyStore.m#L27-L45) implementations appear to do.